# Is it possible to add a javascript function to local state with apollo-link-state?

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client

Basicly I want to do something like this (add the function myCallback to the callBack field of a todo):

./resolvers/todos:

```
const myCallback = () => {
  console.log('callback run');
};

const todos = {
  defaults: {
    todos: [
      {
        id: '2',
        text: 'Hi',
        completed: false,
        callBack: myCallback, // <-- Add the callback here
        __typename: 'todo',
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default todos;
```

But i get error: Error: Error writing result to store for query undefined/nCannot read property 'substring' of undefined

My app gets initialized like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

import todos from './resolvers/todos';

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: withClientState({ ...todos, cache }),
});

render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <div />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Is this possible to do with apollo-link-state or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't have a direct quote on this, but i am pretty sure this isn't supported - for one GraphQL doesn't support a type of function... and you can't store functions in a Json-Object which the cache is normalized to... Also it could lead to terrible security issues too... I think one possebiltiy to store a function into apollo-cache would be transforming it to a string - and storing it that way... then, when receiving use eval-methode 'eval("console.log('Alive!')";);' to make it executable code... BUT I REALLY REALLY WOULD ADVICE AGAINST THIS.